# How to bind json array in your C# XAML//WPF through Listbox using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json

Tags: c#, json, wpf

How can i display the whole JSON Array for "Telnet and Service". I already have it displaying the MachineName, Ping and the first data for Telnet and Service but not the 2nd data for Telnet and Service. I used System.Runtime.Serialization.Json and not Newtonsoft.

My xaml

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModels:Rootobject/>
</Window.DataContext>


<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="listboxMachine"                  
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Gray" BorderThickness="0"
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
             ItemsSource="{Binding server}">

        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <StackPanel >
                        <Image Width="80" Source="http://fakeimg.pl/100x200/?text=Image_{i}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MachineName}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Ping}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Telnet/Description}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Telnet/Port}" />

                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

</Grid>
```

Code behind

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        JsonRead();
    }

    public void JsonRead()
    {
        using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead("D:\\file.json"))
        {
            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Rootobject));
            Rootobject rootobject = (Rootobject)serializer.ReadObject(stream);

            listboxMachine.ItemsSource = rootobject.server;


        }
    }


}
```

Json File

```
{  "server": [
{
  "MachineName": "Server1",
  "Ping": "Server1.company.com",
  "Telnet": [
    {
      "Description": "IIS Application",
      "Port": 80
    },
    {
      "Description": "Java Application",
      "Port": 8080
    }
  ],
  "Service": [
    {
      "Description": "IIS Service",
      "Value": "iisSomething"
    },
    {
      "Description": "Java Service",
      "Value": "javaSomething"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "MachineName": "Server2",
  "Ping": "Server2.company.com",
  "Telnet": [
    {
      "Description": "IIS Application",
      "Port": 80
    },
    {
      "Description": "Java Application",
      "Port": 8080
    }
  ],
  "Service": [
    {
      "Description": "IIS Service",
      "Value": "iisSomething"
    },
    {
      "Description": "Java Service",
      "Value": "javaSomething"
    }
  ]
}
] }
```

Server.cs

```
public class Server
{
    public string MachineName { get; set; }
    public string Ping { get; set; }
    public List<Telnet> Telnet { get; set; }
    public List<Service> Service { get; set; }
}

public class Telnet
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Port { get; set; }
}

public class Service
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

MainModel.cs

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public List<Server> server { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How do you want the data to be displayed? Are you assuming there will always be 2 items in the `Telnet` and `Service` collections, or is it an arbitrary number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot display `a list of items` (List of Telnet) in a `TextBlock`, you need to use an `ItemsControl` like `ListBox`.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <StackPanel >
            <Image Width="80" Source="http://fakeimg.pl/100x200/?text=Image_{i}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MachineName}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Ping}"/>

            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Telnet}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Margin="5, 0" Content="{Binding Description}" />
                            <Label Content="{Binding Port}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>

            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Service}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Margin="5, 0" Content="{Binding Description}" />
                            <Label Content="{Binding Value}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>

            <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding Telnet/Description}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Telnet/Port}" />-->

        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thank you. I was missing the <ListBox ItemSource> portion. Another lesson learned for me.